# Game with computers choosing the worst possible moves

Tags: engines, analysis, strategy, tactics, computer-chess

Since chess engines in one way or an other rank alternative moves, it should be able to search for the worst move as well as the best. Have engines played each others trying to lose, and what has come out of that? Do they for instance set up for devastating tactics against themselves? *(It might be a style of chess that I recognize...)*

Comment: Are you talking about [loser chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/6501/has-loser-chess-been-solved), as that has been solved?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Chess engines can be reprogrammed to play a bad move. This is not very hard, just pointless and waste of time.

Some possibilities:

- Choose the worst move statically without even going into search
- Choose a move randomly from the move generator
- For each legal move in the position, play it internally and the run a regular search. Choose the move that gives the worst score.
- Reverse piece material sign, so that the engine would give away materials for free. For example, scoring +9 for giving away the queen without any compensation.
- Similarly, play around the piece square table values.

A few years ago, someone made a chess engine **Moron** for exactly what you descrbe.

> http://talkchess.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=47026&highlight=julien+loser

Comment: But what if the opponent tries the same thing. And not according to some made up "loser chess rules", but just lose in ordinary chess. Why would it be harder to deliberately lose in chess than it is to win?

Comment: @LocalFluff I am not so sure I understand. Can you edit your question?